# Как использовать final значения внутри CustomView?

Tags: android

Как использовать final значения внутри CustomView? Пытаюсь сделать следующим образом:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    private static final int x;

    public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        x = getX();
    }
}
```

, но пишет, что переменная не инициализирована. Сразу указывать значение при объявлении не хочется, так как необходимо будет это значение сначала достать из кода.

Comment: А обязательно ли делать переменную final? Если вы присваиваете ей значение в процессе работы программы - то она теряет определение константы

Comment: @Werder если она final, студия не даст её изменить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема у вас в static, а не в final. Либо инициализируйте ее, либо объявите как не static. Статические переменные инициализируеются при загрузке класса (не путать с созданием объекта класса).

Впрочем вы можете-таки инициализировать переменную "из кода", точнее из статического метода.

```
private static final int x;
static {
  x = getX();
}

private static int getX(){
  return 100500;
}
```

или просто

```
private static final int x = getX();
```

или еще проще

```
private static final int x = 100500;
```

Comment: Выходит создать статическую переменную зависимую от Context не выйдет, да и думаю не сильно хорошо это.

Comment: и получается не выйдет использовать final переменные внутри CustomView или Fragment-а, значения которых, зависит от того же Context, так как в конструкторе они ещё не присоединились к Activity.